# Data Binding from sql to text box isnt working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

have a simple WPF window with a text box.  In this window I want to display a single userId.  This is a such a simple process in winforms, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it in XAML.
The code is a simple class - User which is lists as follows...

```
public class User
    {
        private string userId;
        private string employeeNumber;
        ...

        public User()
        { }

        public string UserId
        {
            get
            { 
            return userId;
            }
            set
            {
                userId = value;
            }
        }


        public string EmployeeNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeNumber = value;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

The xaml for the wpf window is...

```
<Window
    ...
    <Window.Resources></Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="lblUserId" Content="User Id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblEmployeeNumber" Content="Employee Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbUserId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="200,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tbEmployeeNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="200,106,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the window loads this code behind is executed.

```
public partial class winTest : Window
{
    public winTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private User user;
    private List<User> userList;
    private List<Permissions> permissionsList;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            string userId = "1234";
            user = UserDB.GetUserInfo(userId);
    }

}
...
```

The code for the GetUserInfo is

```
public static User GetUserInfo(string userID)
    {
        User user = new User();
        SqlConnection connection = BusinessDB.GetConnection();
        string selectStatement = "SELECT userid, empno, FROM employees " +
        "WHERE userid = @UserID";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", userID);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            //SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["userid"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    user.UserId = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    user.UserId = (reader["userid"]).ToString();
                }

                if (reader["empno"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    user.EmployeeNumber = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    user.EmployeeNumber = reader["empno"].ToString();
                }
        }
    return user 
    }   
 ...
```

Stepping through the code reveals that user is indeed populated with the correct info - its the binding portion that getting me.  The above xaml does not have any binding listed because I've tried binding it to everything except my dogs nose and I still get empty text boxes.
Can anyone please help a wpf newbie out? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to make your `User` a public property, not a private field:

   ```
   public User User { get; set }
   ```
2. If you want your binding to respond to changes in the value of `User`, your `Window` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

   ```
   public partial class winTest : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           }
       }

       // <your other winTest code goes here>
   }
   ```
3. Your binding should look like this:

   ```
   <TextBox x:Name="tbUserId"
            Text="{Binding User.UserId}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="23"
            Margin="200,76,0,0"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="120" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As devuxer said, make sure to rewrite your public properties as:

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
```

Try this method on your Window_loaded();

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string userId = "1234";
        user = UserDB.GetUserInfo(userId);
        tbUserId.Text = user.UserId;
        tbEmployeeNumber.Text = user.tbEmployeeNumber;

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you!  very helpful - its why I love this site.